# How do you 'join' multiple SQL data sets side by side (that don't link to each other)?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How would I go about joining results from multiple SQL queries so that they are side by side (but unrelated)?

The reason I am thinking of this is so that I can run 1 query in Google Big Query and it will return 1 single table which I can import into Excel and do some charts.

e.g. Query 1 looks at *dataset TableA* and returns:

```
**Metric:** Sales
**Value:** 3,402
```

And then Query 2 looks at *dataset TableB* and returns:

```
**Name:** John
**DOB:**  13 March
```

They would both use different tables and different filters, etc.

What would I do to make it look like:

```
---Sales----------John----

---3,402-------13 March----
```

Or alternatively:

```
-----Sales--------3,402-----

-----John-------13 March----
```

Or is there a totally different way to do this?

Comment: This is not what SQL is designed for, and there is no inbuilt feature to stitch unrelated data together into rows. Remember SQL was built for "relational data base systems" i.e. information that IS related. Even if such a feature existed there is still 2 queries, one for tableA and another for tableB, why not just accept that and take the result 4 rows into Excel, and  then fiddle with presentation in that tool.

Comment: I am not sure why you would do that.. but you can generate a row number for tables & make a directional join with the tables with the higher count. But do expect null values for non-matching row numbers

Comment: Add row number to each row in both tables, join by row_number.

Comment: Either of your formats is mixing different types in the same column.  That is a red flag that SQL isn't the right tool for this.

Comment: Appreciate all the comments - and understand it's not for SQL but given the constraint that the data I have access to is in Big Query, I wasn't sure what is the next easiest way to get some results and export a single spreadsheet for other users.  Anyway, this Answer provided below works for me - not sure why I didn't think of something so similar like this! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see the use case for the above, I've used something similar to create a single table from multiple tables with different metrics to query in Data Studio so that filters apply to all data in the dataset for example. However in that case, the data did share some dimensions that made it worthwhile doing.

If you are going to put those together with no relationship between the tables, I'd have 4 columns with TYPE describing the data in that row to make for easier filtering.

```
Type | Sales | Name | DOB
```

Use UNION ALL to put the rows together so you have something like

```
"Sales"            | 3402 | null | null
"Customer Details" | null | John | 13 March
```

However, like the others said, make sure you have a good reason to do that otherwise you're just creating a bigger table to query for no reason.